# Update the python interpreter and its modules in Intellij after new pip installs

Tags: python, intellij-idea

I just installed `pandasql` and it upgraded `pandas` from 0.20 to 0.21 automatically.  Intellij stopped "understanding" `pandas` immediately following:

[image]

How can Intellij be requested to re-index/regenerate the python interpreter and its updated modules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not in `Intellij` itself  - but instead with `pip install` on mac not working well with `brew python`: see this post [Why does brew installed python not see the pip installed modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47056147/why-does-brew-installed-python-not-see-the-pip-installed-modules)

As a summary: `pip install` does not make the packages visible to `brew` version of `python`.  A workaround is to use

```
python -m pip install <package>
```

After using that workaround **Intellij automatically detects the newly installed packages** , builds the java wrappers for them and then we see pretty things like this:

[image]

("Look ma no warnings!")